# selecting pairs of values from sql table

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a SQL table with 3 columns: 'from point', 'to point' and 'distance' between points. There is always only one distance for specific pair of points.

```
| from | to  | distance |
|-----------------------|
|  1   | 2   |   15     |
|  1   | 3   |   20     |
|  1   | 4   |   2      |
|  3   | 2   |   16     |
|  4   | 2   |   48     |
|  5   | 2   |   12     |
|  3   | 4   |   19     |
|  3   | 5   |   55     |
|  4   | 5   |   18     |
```

Now I have a list of points, for which I want to get distances between, for example:

```
ids = [1, 2, 4]
```

and I want to return all distances between those points:

```
1-2 -> 15
1-4 -> 2 
2-4 -> 48
```

I have made some code in python that gets me those pairs

```
    pairs=[]
    for a in ids:
        for b in ids:
            if a != b and sorted([a,b]) not in trasy:
                pairs.append(sorted([a,b]))
                print(sorted([a,b]))
```

which I could ask to SQL for getting distances, but in this way each pair will have a new query and the list of ids can be much longer (like up to 50 elements for now) and I don't think that is a good method.

I'm quite new in SQL but I believe that there is some simpler method, would be perfect to get it all with one query

Comment: Does the order of the points matter? The SQL table example you give suggests it does (1->4 is not same distance as 4->1), but the pairs you construct from "ids" suggest it doesn't.

Comment: order doesn't matter, it's just in the table it is not always sorder with the lower number as 'from' and higher as 'to'. There is always one distance for each pair. I did made a mistake that I wrote 4->1 two times - corrected it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the pairs in a single query like this:

```
with points(point_from, point_to, distance) as (
values
    (1, 2, 15),
    (1, 3, 20),
    (1, 4, 2),
    (3, 2, 16),
    (4, 2, 48),
    (5, 2, 12),
    (3, 4, 19),
    (3, 5, 55),
    (4, 1, 68),
    (4, 5, 18)
)

select least(point_from, point_to) as "from", greatest(point_from, point_to) as "to", distance
from points
where point_from in (1, 2, 4) and point_to in (1, 2, 4)

 from | to | distance 
------+----+----------
    1 |  2 |       15
    1 |  4 |        2
    2 |  4 |       48
    1 |  4 |       68
(4 rows)
```

> There is always only one distance for specific pair of points.

Hmm, I do not think so.

Comment: works perfectly as I wanted, there is no need to sort 'from' and 'to', I have made a mistake in post that I wrote 1->4 and 4->1 - there is always one distance for each pair. Anyway thanks for the answer :)